# C# - In debugger, as soon as execution gets to method, attributes set to 0. Then after, they are back

Tags: c#, list

During defineMapCellPositions() and defineMapCellWalls(), map.cols and map.rows change from values such as 4 and 5 to 0, only for the step through of the methods. A step through the debugger confirms this. Why is this?

Any Help Appreciated, thanks!

Whole Map class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Map
{
    public Map()
    {
    }
    public int rows { get; set; }
    public int cols { get; set; }
    public int boardXPos { get; set; }
    public int boardYPos { get; set; }
    public int squareSize { get; set; }

    private List<List<int>> m_cellPositions = new List<List<int>>();
    public List<List<int>> cellPositions
    {
        get
        {
            return m_cellPositions;
        }
        set
        {
            m_cellPositions = value;
        }
    }

    private List<List<int>> m_cellWalls = new List<List<int>>();
    public List<List<int>> cellWalls
    {
        get
        {
            return m_cellWalls;
        }
        set
        {
            m_cellWalls = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Start of MapController Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class MapController
{
    public MapController()
    {
    }

    Map map = new Map();
```

Method to set map.cellWalls

```
public void defineCellWallsList()
{
    //map.cellWalls.Clear();
    for (int row = 0; row < (map.rows * map.cols); row++)
    {
        map.cellWalls.Add(new List<int> { 0, 0 });
    }
}
```

Method to set map.cellPositions

```
public void defineCellPositionsList()
{
    //map.cellPositions.Clear();
    for (int row = 0; row < map.rows; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < map.cols; col++)
        {
            map.cellPositions.Add(new List<int> { col, row });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: map.cols and map.rows are getting set to 0 for a short time while it runs defineCellPositionsList() and defineCellWallsList(). Up to me to figure out why really.

Comment: Where do you set the rows/cols to 4 and 5?

Comment: Is `map.CellPositions` an observable collection?  Any triggers going off when you add items to it?

Comment: @Corak rows and cols get set by a user input in a form. I will show that part now.

Comment: @Corak I hardcoded rows and cols and it looped through making the two jagged lists and they had for example a count of 25, and then after the method finished, the count was 0

Comment: @EdS. Yes i am observing those lists in the debugger. Check my comment above to Corak about what happened last time i observed them. I have never learnt triggers i don't think, so, i'd say no.

Comment: I was referring to PropertyChanged notifications

Comment: @EdS. I don't have any of those. Just observing with a debugger. The list count is 25 which is good, then upon exit of the method, the count goes to 0

Comment: The map being used in your `MapController` doesn't look like it's publicly exposed.  how are you using that `map` instance in the other parts of your code?  It sounds like you are looking at a different instance of a `Map` object, and when you new up a different instance of course all the data will be empty.

Comment: @Caleb This sounds spot on, because i have no idea how to use the same instance, i think it is a different instance. Will inspect now

Comment: I posted an answer bellow with examples of how to expose the `Map` as a public field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expose the instance of `Map` in your `MapController` either make it a public field, or put it in a property.  example:

```
public class MapController
{
    public MapController()
    {
    }

    //here you make it "public" so it is visible to outside classes
    public Map map = new Map();

    // the rest of your code for this class...
```

Then to access that instance (assuming you are holding onto an instance of the controller)

```
var controller = new MapController();
controller.map.rows = 5; // now you can access that instance of map.
controller.map.rows = 123;
```

Now, to inject the Map into the controller (meaning that it is newed up somewhere else in your code, and the same instance can then be shared accross multiple classes using similar injection procedures) you would do something like this...

```
public class MapController
{
    //here you make it "private" cause it doesn't need to be public anymore, 
    //you also don't new it up here, you are passing in a new on during construction.
    private Map map;
    public MapController(Map map)
    {
        this.map = map
    }

    // the rest of your code for this class...
```

Now in the code where you new up the objects and stuff...

```
var map = new Map();
var controller = new MapController(map);
map.rows = 5; // now you can access that instance of map.
map.rows = 123;
// and you can easily share that same instance with other classes
var otherClass = new SomeOtherClassThatNeedsTheMap(map);
```

Comment: Thanks! How do i set the map instance to a variable in other classes as that instance so that i don't have to write controller each time? It is referenced a lot. eg Map map = controller.Map();

Comment: That will really depend on the code structure, but there are several ways to do it.  It sounds to me like you basically want to use the same map all over the place in your code.  I would suggest not creating it in the controller, but `injecting` it into the controller.  I'll update my answer to show you how that works.

Comment: But if you did want to leave the construction in the controller, and just then capture that instance into a variable somewhere else for ease of use, you just do this `var map = controller.map;` (assuming that you left the code with `map` being public on the controller)

Comment: Thanks. It didn't like "private map;" but i figured out that you just for got the type, and did private Map map;. It doesn't seem to like "var", not sure what to do about that

Comment: I think i was planning to define map and controller outside of any method so that i can use it throughout the class and var doesn't work for that

Comment: yeah, fixed it now in the example.  thanks for catching that.
As far as `var` goes, you can only use it when the compiler will know the type as the variable is initialized, so it doesn't work for things that are not initialized in line.

Comment: Im not sure how to inject the map into the controller because the var line of code doesn't work, and if i make a new map without var instead of that, when i do MapController controller = new MapController(map); it complains a field initialiser cannot reference a non-static field

Comment: `static Map map = new Map();
        MapController mapController = new MapController(map);` Is that ok? It has no error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37381/discussion-between-caleb-and-user2602079)